# r assign characters to a column according to values

Tags: r

I have many data frames similar to this:

```
  count value
1   0    7
2   1   230
3   2    5
```

I want to add a column to assign colors according to the "value" column. The biggest one should be red, the second one should be blue, the smallest one should be green.

```
  count value color
1   0    7    blue
2   1   230   red
3   2    5    green
```

Is there an easy way to do it in R? Thanks!

Comment: Try with `rank` i.e. `c("green", "blue", "red")[rank(df1$value)]`

Comment: Thank, akrun! Your solution is so simple and elegant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `rank` from `base R` to create the 'color'

```
df1$color <- c("green", "blue", "red")[rank(df1$value)]
```

Comment: Also (for fun) `c("green", "blue", "red")[order(order(df1$value))]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr` package

```
df <- data.frame(count = c(0,1,2), value = c(7,230,5))
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(color = ifelse(value == min(value), "green", ifelse(value == max(value), "red", "blue")))
```

Comment: Seems like you only using `dplyr` to assign a new column

Answer (score 1):

We can use `dplyr::case_when`.

```
dt <- data.frame(count = c(0, 1, 2), value = c(7, 230, 5))

library(dplyr)

dt2 <- dt %>%
  mutate(color = case_when(
    value == max(value) ~ "red",
    value == min(value) ~ "green",
    TRUE                ~ "blue"
  ))
```

Or create the `Rank` column first and then assign the values based on `Rank` column.

```
dt2 <- dt %>%
  mutate(Rank = dense_rank(value)) %>%
  mutate(color = case_when(
    Rank == 1 ~ "green",
    Rank == 2 ~ "blue",
    Rank == 3 ~ "Red"
  )) %>%
  select(-Rank)
```